# Remove distraction free mode from teeny editor

Tags: customization, tinymce, wp-editor

I'm trying to remove the distraction free mode button from the editor, but i can't make it disapear.

Here is the code im using:

```
  add_filter( 'wp_editor_settings', function($settings) {
    $settings['teeny']=true;
    $settings['media_buttons']=false;
    $settings['quicktags'] = false;
    $settings['dfw'] = false;
    return $settings;
  });
```

Is there something i'm missing? Because this works on the regular editor.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
function allow_distraction_free( $expand, $post_type ) {
    return false;
}

add_filter( 'wp_editor_expand', 'allow_distraction_free', 10, 2);
```

This tested and works as per https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_editor_expand/ and via https://gist.github.com/jwondrusch/41130a421a2a70b0e697 found by googling 'disable distraction free mode'.  The link offers example to tailor by post type.

EDIT: screenshot added from wp 4.9.9. alpha
[image]

Comment: Hi, this code had a strange behavior, it had no effect on the teeny mode activated, and on normal tiny MCE mode it just changed the place the dfw button is.

Comment: HI, I'm testing in 4.9.9 alpha with very few other plugins active and there is no distraction free button mixed in with the other buttons - only the one on the far right, which disappears with code above.   Perhaps the button was also being added by other code adjusting the tiny-mce?  Or it's a version thing.  Let us know if you figure it out.

Comment: Hi again, added screenshot above from wp 4.9.9 alpha.  It looks like it is the same 'dfw' button, there is css absolutely positioning it in the top right.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the feedback, I think it may have something to do with some code that was changing the toolbar buttons. I didn't notice there was as "fullscreen" button there. So when i removed the dfw button it started to show this fullscreen one that appears to be the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

So after researching some wordpress filters i found the teeny_mce_buttons and removed the distraction free button with this function.

```
  function remove_teeny_mce_btns($buttons) {
    unset($buttons[13]);
    return $buttons;
    }

    add_filter('teeny_mce_buttons', 'remove_teeny_mce_btns');
```

Here is the link with the solution:

https://www.gavick.com/blog/wordpress-tinymce-custom-buttons